# Struggling with (understanding) PHP Asynchronous Requests

Tags: php, asynchronous, guzzle

I'm really struggling to understand the way PHP asynchronous requests work. It seems to me that there cannot be any true asynchronous behaviour in PHP because to receive a response from an asynchronous request, you have to delay execution of the script (blocking, essentially) which then defeats the purpose.. right?

What I'm trying to do from a page on my site is:

1. Initiate AJAX request to (local) controller to begin the remote API
   requests
2. Use a loop of GuzzleHTTP requests to remote API
3. Upon completion of each request, send the result to a socket.io server which then emits a message back to the listening client (the original page that initiated the AJAX request)

Now, I have this working - with one caveat: the GuzzleHTTP requests are not asynchronous and the remote API is very slow (usually takes around 10 seconds to receive the JSON response) so when there are 10 tasks, my connection to the server is frozen for over a minute. Opening new tabs/windows and trying to access the site results in waiting until the original script run has completed.

This seems to indicate that I misunderstood how HTTP requests work. I thought that each individual browser window (or request) was completely separate as far as the server is concerned but from the result I'm seeing, perhaps this is not exactly the case?

This is why I started looking into asynchronous requests and discovered that they don't really seem all that.. asynchronous.

So what I'm really looking for is help filling the gaps/misunderstandings in my knowledge of:

- Why the blocking occurs in the first place (in terms of new, completely separate requests)
- Where I might look to implement a solution.

Comment: PHP does not make *any* asynchronous requests. AJAX makes the asynchronous request and each request is separate.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: That's not entirely true: [guzzle does support them](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/faq.html#can-guzzle-send-asynchronous-requests). Sure, the implementation isn't _Really_ async, but it amounts to the same thing

Comment: Thanks for the info @EliasVanOotegem, I didn't know that. So it is pseudo-async?

Comment: "pseudo-asynch" is exactly how I was about to put it. I think it uses closures to simulate a process after the request has completed.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: Not really, I've not looked into the details, but AFAIK it doesn't run the request in a separate process. The trick that guzzle seems to use is to return an instance of `Promise`, which is referenced in a task queue. Each time you access the `Promise`, its state is updated behind the scenes by hooking in several callbacks. The net result is that your request call (`requestAsync`) returns before the request is made, and each time a chunk of the response is received, it's handled by an extra callback. It's basically gathering state at intermittent stages